# How do you multiply 2 dimmed ranges using vba

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a macro to import 30 random numbers, and multiply each one by a predefined population. 
I can't use fixed ranges as the range will be different for each use. 
I have got it all working, except for the multiplication part - I can't get that line of code to compile.

```
Dim N As Integer                                 '(counter)
Dim rng As Range                                 '(activecell address)
Dim rand As String                               '(convert address to string)
Dim pop As Range                                 '(population address - absolute reference)
Dim pop1 As String                               '(population address as string)

N = 0
ActiveCell.Formula = "Population:"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select                   '(select cell next to population)
Set pop = ActiveCell                             '(create absolute reference point)
pop1 = pop.Address                               '(convert to string)
ActiveCell.Offset(2, -1).Select                  '(move to starting point for random)
Do Until N = 30
    N = N + 1                                    '(count for loop)
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ROUNDUP(RAND(),4)" '(random formula)
    ActiveCell.Copy
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Set rng = ActiveCell                         '(set address for multiplication)
    rand = rng                                   '(convert address to string)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select               '(move to next column to multiply)
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & pop & "*" & rng" '(ERROR)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
Loop
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
```

If I start at A1 and press the macro, I expect B3 to have the following formula in it:
=$A$3*$B$1
and for this to be repeated up until B33.

Comment: How are you deciding the range each time?  Your code's pretty confusing.  I've got a couple of solutions (posted as an answer below), but can't figure out how you're deciding the range.

Comment: Change your line to `ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & pop.Address & "*" & rng.Address`

Comment: that worked perfectly! I had tried that, but didn't have any spaces. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the two procedures below will populate your range, although I can't figure out how you're picking your range (so have hard-coded the ranges in).

The first uses an array formula:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim multiplier As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:B7")
    Set multiplier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

    rng.Offset(, 1).FormulaArray = "=" & rng.Address & "*" & multiplier

End Sub
```

This method uses separate formula for each row:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim multiplier As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:B7")
    Set multiplier = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

    rng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1).Formula = "=" & rng.Resize(1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & "*" & multiplier
    rng.Offset(, 1).FillDown

End Sub
```

Following on from your comment below you could use:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim multiplier As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set cell = ActiveCell   'Grab the ActiveCell reference.
    cell = "Population:"

    '2 cells down from the ActiveCell and resized to 30 cells.
    With cell.Offset(2).Resize(30)

        'Add random values and remove the formula.
        .Formula = "=ROUNDUP(RAND(),4)"
        .Value = .Value

        'Add the multiplication formula and fill down.
        .Offset(, 1).Resize(1).Formula = _
            "=" & .Resize(1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & "*" & cell.Offset(, 1).Address
        .Offset(, 1).FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

Further reading:  [FillDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.FillDown), [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Resize) & [With...End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)

Comment: I need the range to be dynamic, so I can't use a fixed range. It needs to run in whichever cell is selected and everything needs to move around and paste in the correct places. I know it is confusing code, but it's working now! thanks :)

Comment: Have added another block of code which should suit your needs.  Hopefully easier to read as well. :)